# Ruby on Rails: uninitialized constant AdminController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently trying to set up an admin page. I'm creating a form in the page where I can update user's profile using checkboxes, but when I tried to submit, I get sent to a routing error page with `uninitialized constant AdminController`

my **routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do 
  get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/' 
end
resources :admin do
 collection  do
    post :edit_multiple
    put :update_multiple
  end
end
```

**controllers/admin/dashboard_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @admin = User.new
  end

  def edit_multiple
  end

  def update_multiple
  end
end
```

**views/admin/dashboard/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag edit_multiple_admin_index_path do |f| %>
<table>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if !user.public %>
  <tr>  
    <td><%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %>
<% end %>
```

Anyone know when I'm getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `routes.rb` file to:

```
namespace :admin do 
  get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/' 
  resource :dashboard do
    post :edit_multiple
    put :update_multiple
  end
end
```

Comment: I changed it, and then I had to change my form_tag to `edit_multiple_admin_dashboard_path`, then I get another error: `uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardsController`at this URL: `http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/edit_multiple`

Comment: Controller names should be plural (in contrary to models, which should be singular) - that's rails convention (over configuration) and you should stick to it. Change file name and class name to plural version as rails expects it to be plural (that can be changed but that's not a good option).